# tell 3gpp from 3gpp2 (GSM from CDMA) SMS/PDU in Android

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I want to receive a SMS delivery notification in an Android app.
I could register a `BroadcastReceiver`, get the pdu, construct a `SmsMessage` from the pdu, and get the status code (`sms.getStatus()`).
 See
[Android SMS delivery notification on failure: false positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174463/android-sms-delivery-notification-on-failure-false-positive) .

Now, the status code is either a CDMA(3gpp2) status code shifted left by 16 bits, or a GSM(3gpp) status code.

To know what the status code 0 means, I have to tell a CDMA message from a GSM one.

For CDMA,

```
0 = Message accepted
2 = Message delivered
```

while for GSM

```
0 = Short message received by the SME
# that is, by the recipient phone
```

The Android source guesses the message type from the network type, but unfortunately this stuff is declared as either `private` or `@hide`.

Given a pdu, I need to find out its format to be able to interpret the zero status code.

Answer (score 0):

The intent from which I extract the pdu has another extra: `format => 3gpp`.
Not sure if all phones would provide it and starting from which API level.